# how to use * in sh string comparison

Tags: sh

How to correctly use * in sh? I tried googling it but couldn't find anything. The following echo ture. why is that?

```
file="test test"

if [ "$file" != "te"* ]

then

   echo true

else

   echo false

fi
```

Comment: `$file`  ("`test`") does equal `"te"*`. So when you ask `$file != "te"*` you will get `false`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin sorry, I forgot to change file.  Why is that when file="test test" it echo false? Does it treat it differently?

Comment: No, you are testing `"te......."` where `"...."` can be anything. As long as `"$file"` begins with `'te'` it will match.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I apologize again, I got all mixed up. Yes you're right it should echo false. The issue I have is when I run it, it gives me true.

Comment: To properly test in POSIX shell, you really want `if [ $(expr "$file" : "te.*") -gt 0 ]` . if No match `$(expr "$file" : "te.*")` will be `0`. Another equivalent expression is `$(expr match "$file" "te.*")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid all the potential problems, when using POSIX shell, you should consider using the old `expr` regex or match expressions. Your choices are:

```
#!/bin/sh

file="test test"

if [ $(expr "$file" : "te.*") -gt 0 ]
then
    echo true
else
    echo false
fi
```

or

```
if [ $(expr substr "$file" 1 2) = "te" ]
then
    echo true
else
    echo false
fi
```

Not elegant, but they are the proper tools for the shell. A short explanation of each and the `expr` syntax for each is:

```
string : regularExp          : returns the length of string if both sides match, 
                               returns 0 otherwise
match string regularExp      : same as the previous one
substr string start length   : returns the substring of string starting from 
                               start and consisting of length characters
```

Comment: You can also simply test the exit status of `expr`, which will be 0 if a match is made, 1 if not.

Comment: Good point, but you would still need to do something with the output in either case if you simply run the command on the previous line before testing `$?`. I guess redirecting to `/dev/null` works in that case too. Did you have something different in mind aside from that case?

Comment: Nope, I'd just use `if expr "$file" : "the.*" > /dev/null; then`.

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of googling and found a good bash scripting resource: 
[Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)

There is a segment that answers your question:

```
[[ $a == z* ]]   # True if $a starts with an "z" (pattern matching).
[[ $a == "z*" ]] # True if $a is equal to z* (literal matching).

[ $a == z* ]     # File globbing and word splitting take place.
[ "$a" == "z*" ] # True if $a is equal to z* (literal matching).
```

So in your case the condition should be:

```
if [[ file != te* ]]
```

Comment: The ABS is actually *not* a great resource, even for bash.

Comment: @chepner Any better study guides you can point me towards? (for future reference)